# Why does the Edge user agent contain other browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, user-agent, microsoft-edge

I was poking around Microsoft Edge and ran the peacekeeper browser benchmarker (I know it's outdated) and when the brenchmark was all finished it thought my browser was Chrome. I took a look at my useragent and could see why-

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393`

Is there a reason Edge has Chrome and Safari in it's user agent? Are the versions essentially "compatible-with" versions?

Comment: "Are the versions essentially 'compatible-with' versions?" Yes. Blame the WebKit monoculture, and authors coding exclusively for WebKit-based browsers.

Comment: https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/06/17/building-a-more-interoperable-web-with-microsoft-edge/